# ContextMenu not displaying, and I don't know why

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu

I'm writing a C# (.NET 3.5) app with a usercontrol that inherits from DataGridView. When the user right-clicks a column header, I want to display a context menu.

I've actually got this working find on 2 forms in my app. I'm stumped because the ContextMenu won't show on the same control on a third form. I do see that the Popup event gets fired, but I don't see the menu being drawn on the screen, and none of the menu item event handlers are getting called.

I have absolutely no idea why my context menu isn't being drawn, and it's driving me batty.

Unfortunately, my code is too complex to post all of it here... I'm including the short section where I build and display the menu. I'm not convinced the problem is in this code, but I don't know where else it would be.

```
if (hti.RowIndex == -1)
{
    ClickedColumnHeader = this.Columns[hti.ColumnIndex];

    //Build a context menu and show it.
    ContextMenu mnu = new ContextMenu();
    mnu.MenuItems.Clear();
    MenuItem mnuHide = new MenuItem("Hide");
    mnuHide.Click += new EventHandler(mnuHide_Click);
    MenuItem mnuRename = new MenuItem("Rename...");
    mnuRename.Click += new EventHandler(mnuRename_Click);
    MenuItem mnuCurrencyFormat = new MenuItem("Format as Currency");
    mnuCurrencyFormat.Checked = false;

    if (this.Columns[hti.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Format == "c")
    {
        mnuCurrencyFormat.Checked = true;
    }
    mnuCurrencyFormat.Click += new EventHandler(mnuCurrencyFormat_Click);
    MenuItem mnuSeparator = new MenuItem("-");
    MenuItem mnuShow = new MenuItem("Show");

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in this.Columns)
    {
        if (col.Visible == false)
        {
            MenuItem x = new MenuItem(col.HeaderText);
            x.Click += new EventHandler(x_Click);
            mnuShow.MenuItems.Add(x);
        }
    }

    mnu.MenuItems.Add(mnuHide);
    mnu.MenuItems.Add(mnuRename);
    mnu.MenuItems.Add(mnuCurrencyFormat);
    mnu.MenuItems.Add(mnuSeparator);
    mnu.MenuItems.Add(mnuShow);

    //for debugging...
    mnu.Popup += new EventHandler(mnu_Popup);
    mnu.Collapse += new EventHandler(mnu_Collapse);

    mnu.Show(this, new System.Drawing.Point(f.X, f.Y));
}
```

I'd really appreciate any assistance the community could offer. I'm really hoping I'm just doing something dumb here.

Comment: You don't need to show all your code, but building a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem would quite possibly help you to solve it yourself, and would *definitely* make it easier for others help.

Comment: I know. But with 30+ files in the project, and the usercontrol that has the problem being 275+ lines of code, and all sorts of data dependencies, trying to whittle this down to the minimum needed to repro represents quite a bit of work. I've never heard of ContextMenu.Show() not showing anything. I'm hoping someone else has. If not, I'll do the work needed to come up with a bare-bones repro.

Comment: Try doing a diff of your forms (where the control is displaying menu vs other form where it is not working).

Answer (score 0):

yup, not enough info to re-create the issue but may I offer this, if you have it working on the other 2 forms, the issue is not with your inherited code. The issue is with the 3rd form.

> If you really feel like taking the
>   time try making a 4th from scratch and
>   see if the same error crops up. Check
>   all of the event handlers. It sounds
>   like you have one wired on forms 1 & 2
>   but not on 3.